# Kentico global webpart usage

Tags: kentico

We're moving from a pure portal to a portal/aspx development model. So I've been working on getting my .Master pages working and so far so good, except i need a way to have a Editable Text webpart applied globally.

Imaging a block of copy that sits in the header and appears on each page.

So, in portal, the copy is entered, and this is used through out the site, regardless of the template. I know i can add static copy to the parent .Master page, but this needs to be editable by an admin.

I've tried registering the Editable Text webpart on the ASPX page, but this doesn't seem to work correctly in the portal.

Comment: I found this in the v9 documention: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/CMSEditableRegion

It seems to be doing what i'm looking, i'll update when i'm confident.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to accomplish this is to create a single page template that has only the editable text webpart on it and does not inherit any other content.  Then on your master page, add a page placeholder which uses that editable text webpart page template.  This should then display that on every page.  I've not done this approach before but hypothetically speaking it should work.

Comment: From what i've seen, when you're template is set to portal & .aspx, there is no master template. So when you create a new page, you can inherit, or base it off a template.

When i inherit, the editable text zone is blank in the page tab.

Is there a web zone that will display from a page? So rather than an editable text web zone, a webzone that pulls in a specifc page. That page has no mark up other than p tags.

Comment: I went down a rabbit hole and going to take a step back and re-look at this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a Custom Setting.

The Kentico documentation has a great [How-To guide](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Adding+custom+website+settings) for that.

After that, you can then just reference it using a macro like `{% Settings.MyCustomSetting %}` on each page - this also allows you to then control how the text is rendered on each section, in case some sections have specific  markup you need to apply to the text block.

Comment: This was my first thought too, but I've also made the mistake of doing this for a site that a few years later was to become multi-lingual which lead to a lot of extra work.

Comment: @DarBrett you are correct, in a multi-lingual environment this would lead to a requirement of multiple settings and that would not bode well for the developer's sanity.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason of converting to Mixed mode? Is it better control over the basic page markup or something else?

Are you aware that you can customize CMSPages/PortalTemplate.aspx or replace it by your custom base page completely?

You may consider to use this approach, and if you need that because some pages are more complex, so it makes more sense to hardcode them, you can also implement them as some larger custom web parts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. One of the main reason for the shift was the requirement for full customization. This is the start of a bigger endeavour  with future tie in the financial back end.

Cheers!

Comment: From my experience almost any requirement can be done in portal engine as well as in ASPX. It is easy to move from PE to ASPX when necessary, so I would recommend to make this decision until you have a specific requirement and running out of options. And even then, I would probably consider going for MVC rather than just ASPX.